# I am not able to submit nested forms in IE6

Tags: html

If the forms are nested, I’m not able to submit them in IE6.

```
<html> <body> <form id="mainform" action="form_action.asp"> <form id="subform" action="form_action1.asp"> <input type="submit" name="FirstName12" value="Mickey" /><br /> </form> First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey" /> <br/> Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse" /> <br/> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </form> </body> </html>
```

I’m not able to submit the `mainform` using the submit button in IE6.
However, I can’t avoid the nesting of forms. This code is just a sample.

Comment: Yes you can avoid nested forms. That's how all the internet works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested forms are not supported in HTML standard.

From [The FORM element](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html)

> There can be several forms in a single document, but the FORM element can't be nested.

Comment: While that is true … HTML 3.0 was an abandoned specification that never made it to Recommendation status and shouldn't be referenced for anything related to real world implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Forms **cannot** be nested in HTML.

```
<!ELEMENT FORM - - (%block;|SCRIPT)+ -(FORM) -- interactive form -->
```

Note that "FORM" is explicitly excluded from the list of things that may be in a form above.

Browsers try to recover from errors, and do so to various degrees, but garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 1):

nested forms cannot be used

Answer (score 1):

forms are not allowed to be nested. (i.e. your subform will be gracefully ignored)